# Airflow DAG not triggered at schedule time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

Below is my DAG code, it is not getting triggered @scheduled time. If i run manually, it is working fine.
Not sure where is the problem. I tried testing two to three corn expression but without any luck.

````
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
#from datetime import timedelta

YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

default_args = {
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
    }

dag = DAG(
    'airflow_worker_pod_monitoring',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='liveness monitoring dag',
    schedule_interval='0,00 15 * * *',
    start_date=YESTERDAY,
    dagrun_timeout=datetime.timedelta(minutes=60))

# priority_weight has type int in Airflow DB, uses the maximum.
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='monitor_pod',
    bash_command='bash /home/airflow/gcs/data/testscript.sh' ,
    dag=dag,
    depends_on_past=False,
    priority_weight=2**31-1)```

How to make this working?
````

Comment: If you reqired more details, edit your question,

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 potential causes of this:

1. `schedule_interval`  provided in  `default_args`
2. Existing DAG's `schedule_interval` was modified
3. `start_date` is set to `datetime.now()`
4. `start_date` not aligned with `schedule_interval`

Your issue could be caused by 2. *or* 4. above since 1. & 3. are properly configured.

Comment: Since it is not working, I used to change schedule_interval? What is the issue with start_date not aligned with schedule_interval. How to fix it?

Comment: After reviewing https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date, you need to focus on 2. for now if it applies to you.

Comment: i will try to delete DAG and re-upload to GCS bucket

Answer (score 0):

Airflow documentation recommends using static data https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date . Using dynamic date (such as airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0)) as start_date is not advisable and may cause issues as the dag gets confused at 00:00 and switch to next day incorrectly. Set your start_date to be a fixed datetime and it should work correctly.

In general, the way the Airflow scheduling works is not always straight forward. I recommend this article going deeper into this topic https://towardsdatascience.com/airflow-schedule-interval-101-bbdda31cc463